# Return value of fprintf

Tags: c, printf, fwrite

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
int main(void)
{
    FILE *fh = fopen ("file.txt", "w");
    if (fh != NULL) {
        int i = 0;
        while(i < 5){
            if (fprintf (fh, "%s", "hello") < 0)
            {
                fprintf (stderr, "err=%d: %s\n", errno, strerror (errno));
            }
            if(ferror(fh))
            {
                printf("wrong\n");
            }
            sleep(10);
        }
    }  
    return(0);
}
```

When I a delete the file "file.txt" during the time the program is running, I expect the fprintf to return a value lesser than 0 to print the error message. But all the times fprintf returns the the size of "hello" string which is 5.

Note: Since there is a sleep call for 10 seconds, I deleted the file before the program terminates.

Clarify me on how to produce the error message if fprintf/fwrite writes to a file which is no longer exists (pointed by the file-descriptor).

Comment: What operating system are you using?

Comment: Linux environment (gentoo)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an another way to check if the directory is deleted or not without reading from the disk.

inotify system call does the job of monitoring a directory and if the directory is deleted, a callback is sent to the main program that created the instance of inotify.

A simple example - This copied from the man page of inotify. [link](http://man7.org/tlpi/code/online/diff/inotify/demo_inotify.c.html)

```
+/* demo_inotify.c
+
+   Demonstrate the use of the inotify API.
+
+   Usage: demo_inotify pathname...
+
+   The program monitors each of the files specified on the command line for all
+   possible file events.
+
+   This program is Linux-specific. The inotify API is available in Linux 2.6.13
+   and later.
+*/
 #include <sys/inotify.h>
 #include <limits.h>
 #include "tlpi_hdr.h"

 static void             /* Display information from inotify_event structure */
 displayInotifyEvent(struct inotify_event *i)
 {
     printf("    wd =%2d; ", i->wd);
     if (i->cookie > 0)
         printf("cookie =%4d; ", i->cookie);

     printf("mask = ");
     if (i->mask & IN_ACCESS)        printf("IN_ACCESS ");
     if (i->mask & IN_ATTRIB)        printf("IN_ATTRIB ");
     if (i->mask & IN_CLOSE_NOWRITE) printf("IN_CLOSE_NOWRITE ");
     if (i->mask & IN_CLOSE_WRITE)   printf("IN_CLOSE_WRITE ");
     if (i->mask & IN_CREATE)        printf("IN_CREATE ");
     if (i->mask & IN_DELETE)        printf("IN_DELETE ");
     if (i->mask & IN_DELETE_SELF)   printf("IN_DELETE_SELF ");
     if (i->mask & IN_IGNORED)       printf("IN_IGNORED ");
     if (i->mask & IN_ISDIR)         printf("IN_ISDIR ");
     if (i->mask & IN_MODIFY)        printf("IN_MODIFY ");
     if (i->mask & IN_MOVE_SELF)     printf("IN_MOVE_SELF ");
     if (i->mask & IN_MOVED_FROM)    printf("IN_MOVED_FROM ");
     if (i->mask & IN_MOVED_TO)      printf("IN_MOVED_TO ");
     if (i->mask & IN_OPEN)          printf("IN_OPEN ");
     if (i->mask & IN_Q_OVERFLOW)    printf("IN_Q_OVERFLOW ");
     if (i->mask & IN_UNMOUNT)       printf("IN_UNMOUNT ");
     printf("\n");

     if (i->len > 0)
         printf("        name = %s\n", i->name);
 }

 #define BUF_LEN (10 * (sizeof(struct inotify_event) + NAME_MAX + 1))

 int
 main(int argc, char *argv[])
 {
     int inotifyFd, wd, j;
     char buf[BUF_LEN] __attribute__ ((aligned(8)));
     ssize_t numRead;
     char *p;
     struct inotify_event *event;

     if (argc < 2 || strcmp(argv[1], "--help") == 0)
         usageErr("%s pathname...\n", argv[0]);

     inotifyFd = inotify_init();                 /* Create inotify instance */
     if (inotifyFd == -1)
         errExit("inotify_init");

+    /* For each command-line argument, add a watch for all events */
+
     for (j = 1; j < argc; j++) {
         wd = inotify_add_watch(inotifyFd, argv[j], IN_ALL_EVENTS);
         if (wd == -1)
             errExit("inotify_add_watch");

         printf("Watching %s using wd %d\n", argv[j], wd);
     }

     for (;;) {                                  /* Read events forever */
         numRead = read(inotifyFd, buf, BUF_LEN);
         if (numRead == 0)
             fatal("read() from inotify fd returned 0!");

         if (numRead == -1)
             errExit("read");

         printf("Read %ld bytes from inotify fd\n", (long) numRead);

         /* Process all of the events in buffer returned by read() */

         for (p = buf; p < buf + numRead; ) {
             event = (struct inotify_event *) p;
             displayInotifyEvent(event);

             p += sizeof(struct inotify_event) + event->len;
         }
     }

     exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
 }
```

Answer (score 5):

On UNIX-like systems, "deleting" a file does not physically delete the file on disk. It merely decreases its link count by 1. The file is not actually deleted until the last link to it goes away. This is why the system call that's invoked by the `rm` command is called `unlink`. `man 2 unlink` for more information.

One consequence of this can be seen if you create a hard link to a file:

```
echo "hello" > file0
ln file0 file1
rm file0
```

The `rm file0` command means that the file is no longer visible by that name, but it's still visible via its other name `file1`. If you then `rm file1`, the actual file will finally vanish.

Another way to prevent a file from being removed is for a process to have it open. Your program creates a file, and creates a directory entry with the name `"file.txt"`. When you type `rm file.txt` outside your program, you remove the directory entry, not the file. Your program can still write to the file. It can even seek back to the beginning of the file and read it again.

If your program calls `fclose(fh)`, or if it terminates (which implicitly closes all open files), then the last reference to the disk file will vanish, and the actual file on disk will be removed.

Non-UNIX systems (like Windows) are likely to behave differently.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. But is there any workaround to find or to validate whether the file pointer/descriptor points to a non-existent file ? I mean any system calls that knows about the file descriptor's memory location etc.

Comment: After you type `rm file.txt`, the file still exists. If you want to know whether the directory entry exists, you can call `fstat(fileno(fh), &buf)`, where `buf` is of type `struct stat`, and check the value of `st_nlink`, the number of hard links. When you create the file, `st_nlink` should be 1; after `rm file.txt` it should be 0. But remember, **the file itself still exists**.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It really helped me to solve the issue. But my doubt is, does fstat reads every time from disk to get file attributes ? Because my aim is to reduce the overall disk read operation. Moreover, does fcntl finds whether the file exists or not ? because it gets file descriptor as argument like fstat.

Comment: @Langdon: I don't know; perhaps someone else can fill in the details.